# Android: how to run a local server in webview? ( = emulate a server in webview)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a server that runs a website (with html, CSS, javascript) accessible from any browser.

Now, I want to run the code of this server locally in a webview of my Android app. For that, I placed all the code of my server in the 'assets' folder of my app.

Now, how should I proceed in order to emulate a server in the webview of my Android app?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "emulate a server"? If you mean "load HTML from assets", then use `file:///android_asset/path/within/your/assets.html` for the URL, where `path/within/your/assets.html` is replaced by whatever the relative path is within `assets/` of the HTML that you wish to render.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your website with WampServer, XAMPP then connect your android phone with same network. After that, you can see your website on your Android phone.